# How can i expand my container as per my text length?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created one widget called slidercarasol in that i had done following :

```
 Widget slidercarasol = FutureBuilder(
        future: GetAlerts(device_id),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return SpinKitChasingDots(
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 50.0,
            );
          } else if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
            return Container(
              height: 100,
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                'NO ALERTS AVAILABLE NOW',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
              )),
            );
          } else {
            return new CarouselSlider(
              aspectRatio: 16 / 5,
              viewportFraction: 1.0,
              autoPlayInterval:  Duration(seconds: 20),
              onPageChanged: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  _current = index;
                });
              },
              autoPlay: true,
              pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 10),
              items: <Widget>[
              for (var ind = 0; ind < snapshot.data.length; ind++)
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(snapshot.data[ind].que,
                        softWrap: true,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
              ],
            );
          }
        });
```

and i had called that widget in scaffold

```
  body: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                color: Colors.black,
                semanticContainer: true,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                child: Stack(

                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  children: <Widget>[

                    Container(

                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        image: new DecorationImage(
                          image: new AssetImage("assets/slideralert.png",),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(10.0)),
                      ),
                      //  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.notifications,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          slidercarasol
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
                elevation: 5,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 24.0, left: 24.0, top: 10.0),
              ),
             otherwidget,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

and i get the output like this,
i need the full text to be shown and the height of the container will be increased as per text is large in length.
i want to display full text in container if the text is short than no issue but when i get long text i am unable to display full text..
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your slidercarasol with Flexible.

```
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.notifications,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            fit: FlexFit.loose,
                            child: slidercarasol,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```